# RestController not returning back JSON when i use AJAX call to submit a JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, forms, rest

Ok guys i'm having this problem, if i submit directly using the form it works fine but recently i had to make some upgrades to the webapp and now i'm literally stuck because of what i explained in the title.

I have this jquery function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var contextroot = "/Progetto/"
            $(".dati").on('submit', function(e) {
                var form = $(".dati");
                var action = form.attr("action");
                if (action == "restAddStudent") {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var data = form.serializeArray();
                    $.ajax({
                        url : contextroot + action,
                        dataType : 'json',
                        type : 'POST',
                        contentType : 'application/json',
                        data : JSON.stringify(getFormData(data)),
                        error : function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log(errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        function getFormData(data) {
            var unindexed_array = data;
            var indexed_array = {};
            $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i) {
                indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
            });
            return indexed_array;
        }
    </script>
```

that submits my data to the RestController, and till this point it works fine.
The problem shows up when my restController should give me the json back, in fact the page doesn't return back any json file.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/restAddStudent", produces = "application/json")
    private Confirmation addStudent(@RequestBody AddStudent addStud) {
        Confirmation result = new Confirmation();
        try {
            String nome = addStud.getNome();
            String cognome = addStud.getCognome();
            long classe = addStud.getClasse();
            Long c = classe;
            logger.debug(
                    String.format("Inizio operazione aggiunta studente [Nome: %s], [Cognome : %s], [ID classe : %d]",
                            nome, cognome, classe));
            StudListDTO studListDTO = new StudListDTO();
            ClassiDTO classDTO = new ClassiDTO();
            classDTO.setID(classe);
            studListDTO.setCognome(cognome);
            studListDTO.setNomeS(nome);
            studListDTO.setClasse(classDTO);
            if (nome != null && cognome != null && c != null) {
                ss.aggiungiStud(studListDTO);
            } else {
                result.setMessage("Non è stato possibile inserire l'utente in quanto sono stati lasciati dei campi in bianco");
                result.setStatus("WARN");
                logger.error("I campi nome o cognome sono vuoti! Impossibile aggiungere lo studente");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Non è stato possibile inserire lo studente", e);
            result.setMessage("Non è stato possibile inserire lo studente");
            result.setStatus("WARN");
        } finally {
            logger.debug("Fine operazione aggiunta studente");
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This method should return me back something like this: [return sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7u92i.png)
but, instead, it doesn't now show me anything.

Comment: I really don't know spring so I cant tell if you modified the server side code to account for the change to consume json via ajax

Comment: @Andreas i don't think you can submit a form in JSON, this is why i used a jquery function, to convert form fields in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller method looks strange..

You are returning Confirmation but it seems to only be set when something goes wrong. Are you sure you are returning the correct object?

Also your controller should be public not private.

And remove produces = "application/json" and use MediaType.Application.JSON instead